# bash http proxy username password

Tags: bash, curl, proxy

How to make bash http proxy work if there is @ in password string.

`export http_proxy='http://jdoe:P@ssw0rd@proxyserver:8080'`.

I am getting `curl: (5) Couldn't resolve proxy 'ssword@proxyserver'` for the next curl command. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL-encode special characters. `@` is `%40`

```
export http_proxy='http://jdoe:P%40ssw0rd@proxyserver:8080'
```